# Read unprocessed messages in Apache Kafka using Simple Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

i tired following the link

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example

to use SimpleConsumer to consume messages but while using it I found some abrupt behavior as follows:

The consumers are consuming messages from a specific partition. But the issue is that When my consumer is running and I push messages to the topic using a producer it consumes messages from that partition. But if my consumer is not running at present and I push some messages to the topic and again start the consumer it do not consume the messages which were pushed by the producer but again it is ready to consume messages which will be pushed now. I am using LatestTime() instead od EarliestTime() as I want to consume only unprocessed messages.

For example

Case -1

Consumer is running :

Producer pushed M1, M2, M3 message to partition 1 of topic 1

result: consumer will consume all three messages.

Case - 2

Consumer is not running

producer now pushes m4, m5 m6 messgae to partition 1 of topic 1

consumer is invoked now

result :  consumer donot consume messgaes m4, m5, m6 but If I will check the offset then it is set to 7. This means the producer has advanced the offset to 7 while producing messages as a result the consumer will consume messages from offset 7 now

Please help ideally when when consumer comes up again it should read messages from m4.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong.

First of all I'm not sure `SimpleConsumer` is what you're looking for. It forces you to manage offsets yourself (e.g. it does not commit offsets to Zookeeper at all and every time you start a `SimpleConsumer` again it will fetch the same messages again). `SimpleConsumer` does not have an understanding of a "processed message". All it can do is start fetching from some offset and continue fetching until you say "stop".

Anyway if you intend to commit processed offsets yourself you should use `EarliestTime` (`auto.offset.reset=smallest` config entry). `auto.offset.reset` means that if your consumer is initialized with wrong offset (and `SimpleConsumer` is initialized with `-1` offset if I remember correctly, which is obviously wrong) it will reset to either `smallest` available (`EarliestTime`) or `largest` available (`LatestTime`) offset.

To make it clearer here's the example:

your `Case-1`:

you create a consumer and point it to topic 1 partition 1. As it is initialized with wrong offset initially, it will ask the broker for some proper offset (here is where the `smallest` or `largest` offset reset comes in). In case when you did not yet produce any message the `smallest` and `largest` offsets will both be `0`, so when you produce some messages your consumer will fetch these messages.

`Case-2`:

you produce N messages (say 7). Then you start your `SimpleConsumer`. Again, it is initialized with wrong offset and asks the broker for proper offset. With `smallest` reset offset it will be `0`, and with `largest` offset it will be `7`. As in your example you use `LargestOffsets` your consumer will re-initialize with offset `7` and start consuming from it.

In general take a look at high-level consumer, in most cases that's what you are looking for.
Here's the [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example)

Comment: but If I use the HighLevelConsumer then it do not provide me the way to associate a consumer to specific partition in a toipc. My requirement is - I have n producers each attached to a specific partition and n consumers each attached to a specific partition. The partitioning is done on the basis of some key. So I picked up SimpleConsumer in this case.

Comment: @ajaymittal Then unfortunately you'll have to manage offsets yourself. High level consumer does not provide configurations to consume specific partitions.

Comment: While using SimpleConsumer I can get only the smallest offset using EarliestTime() as 0 or latestTime() gives the recent one. Is there some way to get the offset point to index of unprocessed messages.

Comment: You'll have to track processed offsets yourself in some way. High level consumer uses Zookeeper for this. SimpleConsumer NEVER commits consumed offsets so it doesn't know what messages have been already processed. You'll have to track the last processed offset yourself in some way and when you restart the consumer you should initialize it with this stored offset manually.